# In excel, how do I write a formula that understands blank cells are 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

In excel I have the following formula in `J8` cell:

```
=SUM(IF($C8="DBS",SUM($G8-$F8),0)+$J7)
```

If `G8` or `FB` are blank the result in `J8` is `#VALUE!`, if I type 0 the correct answer is displayed. I do not want to clutter the table with 0's, now spend the time updating the spreadsheet every time new data is imported.

Comment: This is not your question, but I do not know of a reason to use `SUM($G8-$F8)` instead of just `$G8-$F8`.

Comment: Is this an Excel 2011 thing? Excel 2019 already seems to treat blank cells as 0..

Comment: Are you certain the cells are blank? Is there a formula in those cells?  If so, please copy/paste.  Truly blank cells are treated as `0`, but cells containing a non-printing character or space are not and will --> `#VALUE!` in your formula.

Answer (score 7):

As a reference: https://excel.tips.net/T002174

You can combine `IF(condition, value_for_true, value_for_false)` and `ISBLANK(cell)` to replace `$G8` with `IF(ISBLANK($G8), 0, $G8)`

Comment: `=$J7+IF($C8<>"DBS",0,IF(ISBLANK($G8),0,$G8)-IF(ISBLANK($F8),0,$F8))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below to add in extra IFs.

```
=SUM(IF($C8="DBS",SUM(IF(TRIM($G8)="",0,$G8)-IF(TRIM($F8)="",0,$F8),0)+$J7)
```

You can use multiple IF statements through out a formula.

Also you don't actually need to use SUM here. you can just use:

```
=IF($C8="DBS",IF(TRIM($G8)="",0,$G8)-IF(TRIM)$F8="",0,$F8),0)+$J7
```

I have added TRIM in here, as your original formula should be working, you may have some trailing spaces, TRIM will remove these.